# python generators and concurrency

Tags: python, concurrency, multiprocessing, generator

I have an generator which returns file names and an NLP task from NLTK / spaCy. I want to perform this task in parallel (for each document), i.e. process k documents in parallel.

How can I perform this operation in python? Is the multiprocessing package or asyncIo the way to go? Or pyAkka?

The returned results will be added to an inverted index as shown in the example below.

```
def gen_items():
    print("Yield 0")
    yield (0, 'Text 0')
    print("Yield 1")
    yield (1, 'text 1')
    print("Yield 2")
    yield (2, 'Text 2')

gen1, gen2 = itertools.tee(gen_items())
ids = (id_ for (id_, text) in gen1)
texts = (text for (id_, text) in gen2)
docs = nlp.pipe(texts, batch_size=50, n_threads=4)
d = {}
for id_, doc in zip(ids, docs):
    print('id ' + str(id_))
    for token in doc:
       # print('token ' + str(token) + ' orth ' + token.orth_)
        if token.is_alpha and not token.is_stop and len(token.orth_) > 1:
            strtok = token.orth_.strip()
            if strtok not in d.keys():
                d[strtok] = {id_}
            elif strtok in d.keys():
                d[strtok].add(id_)
```

Comment: `nlp.pipe(texts, batch_size=50, n_threads=4)` Is this already using threads to handle your desired parallelism?  (I am unfamiliar with NLTK and NLP)

Comment: Apparently not or only partially https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/926